# What is a ZSET in Redis database?

Tags: redis

What is a zset in a redis database.
I have a redis database with some data. In order to get the values

```
KEYS *apple*

1) "compleet-index:products:apple"
2) "compleet-index:brands:apple"
```

after to get the key

```
GET  compleet-index:productos:apple
```

and I had the response

```
(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

I get the type

```
TYPE  compleet-index:productos:iphone

zset
```

When I make

```
DUMP  compleet-index:productos:iphone
```

I obtain an exas codes.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Short answer: Use `ZRANGE compleet-index:products:apple 0 -1 WITHSCORES`

ZSET is a short name for *Redis Sorted Set*, a Redis data type [documented here](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro). Each key in a sorted set has multiple values inside, associated with a floating value score.